# Snowflake: Procedure with ARRAY parameter called from another procedure

Tags: javascript, arrays, binding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to bind an array to a call in a procedure.

I get the following error message:

> Execution error in stored procedure TEST_CALL_DO_WITH_ARR: Invalid binds argumentGabi,Klaus,Sabine.
> Error: Unsupported type for binding argument 2undefined At Snowflake.execute, line 2 position 25

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_DO_WITH_ARR(ARR ARRAY )
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    // Do something with the Array
    return 'OK' ;
$$
;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_CALL_DO_WITH_ARR()
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    var Param_ARRAY =  ['Gabi','Klaus','Sabine'] ;
    var stmt = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: "CALL Test_DO_WITH_ARR(:1)", binds: [Param_ARRAY] });
    return stmt ;
$$
;

CALL Test_CALL_DO_WITH_ARR() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Snowflake Stored Procedure in JS only supports **number, string** and **SfDate** as bind variables, as stated here in our documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#binding-variables

> Currently, only JavaScript variables of type number, string, and
> SfDate can be bound.

The workaround would be to pass as String and convert them into Array using JS in the inner function call.